# Performance impact of upsert vs index(with custom doc id) in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a huge traffic coming out of kafka which we are continuously ingesting to es using Index api(with custom doc id). Due to some edge cases we are thinking of moving to update api(upsert with doc_as_upsert with update and insert fields). Will there be any performance impact due to this? We won't be able to afford any lags here as expectation is it will be near real time. So wanted to be double sure if there will be any performance implications due to this.

So far from our readings couldn't find much materials which indicates any performance issues.

Sample code

**Current implementation**

`POST /index-1/_doc/abc`

`{"field1": "value1","field2": "value2"}`

**To be implementation**
`POST /index-1/_update/abc`

`{"doc":{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"},"upsert":{"field1":"value1","field3":"value3"}}`

Comment: From my experience - no, i haven`t heard\faced any performance issues between these two approaches.